# Function which sets context property value is empty but works. Why?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm making a very basic program using React Context following a tutorial on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fF9vrZNSQC4&t=734s). One part really confused me though, there are two properties in the default context:

```
import React from "react"

const defaultContext = {
    markdownText: "",
    setMarkdownText: () => {},    
}

export default React.createContext(defaultContext)
```

The setMarkdownText property is never then actually updated and remains an empty function.

```
const {setMarkdownText} = useContext(editorContext)

const onInputChange = e => {
    const newValue = e.currentTarget.value;
    setMarkdownText(newValue)
}
```

Then how is setMarkdownText actually changing the markdownText property despite being an empty function in the code above?

[A link to the complete project on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/markdown-editor-7c199?file=/src/components/result.jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual values are passed to context provider in App.js. Default context values are just safety mechanism in case someone will make consumer without provider.

Here is relevant documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Explanation:

```js
// editorContext.js

// this is our default "fallback" values for context
const defaultContext = {
  markdownText: "",
  setMarkdownText: () => {},
};

// We are creating context instance
export default React.createContext(defaultContext);

// App.js
export default function App() {
  //  this state and state setting fucntion will be our actual context value
  const [markdownText, setMarkdownText] = useState("");
  // we prepare it here
  const contextValue = {
    markdownText,
    // This is our actual `setMarkdownText`
    setMarkdownText,
  };

  // and pass it into EditorContext.Provider as a value prop
  // This value will be used for every consumer inside the tree, instead of default value
  return (
    <EditorContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <AppContainer>
        <Title>Markdown Editor</Title>
        <EditorContainer>
          <MarkedInput />
          <Result />
        </EditorContainer>
      </AppContainer>
    </EditorContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes but the default context function is used in App.js to set the markdown text value. How does that part work?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know how the useState hook works... Just started learning about Hooks and Context today

Comment: I advice you to read documentation once and then with at least some knowledge proceed to courses. Courses often omit "obvious" information and this can be frustrating